Leopard dock in Mojave
is there anyway to get the leopard dock to mojave without cdock. I have the dock. app from leopard system folder but I know replacing it does not work.
Any of you know what code I need to modify to get the reflections and stuff with the scurve.png and indicator.png working? I currently see those image files mentioned above but can't seem to find the file that commands the location that places it. But like there's a file called widgets.wdgt inside the dock folder that has css and js file that tells the app where to place things, but I know that's not related to the dock.
Thanks

Apple makes it increasingly difficult to make cosmetic alterations of the OS.
There's no way to transplant the interface components from Leopard into Mojave.
